# Why I am getting Type Error: Robot() takes no argument?

Tags: class, object

Following is my code:

```
class Robot:
    def __init(self,name, color, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight

    def self_introduce(self):
        print(f"hello my name is {self.name},"
              f" my eye colour is {self.color}"
              f"and my weight is {self.weight} ")



r1 = Robot("johh","Red", 40)
r2 = Robot("murry","Blue", 45)

r1.self_introduce()
r2.self_introduce()
```

I'm getting:
*Error: Robot() takes no argument*

Comment: The method is called `__init__` not `__init`...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line `def __init__(self,name, color, weight):`. You missed `__` after `__init`.

Following is corrected code. See [it working here](https://ideone.com/JmCE7H).

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self,name, color, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight

    def self_introduce(self):
        print(f"hello my name is {self.name},"
              f" my eye colour is {self.color}"
              f"and my weight is {self.weight} ")



r1 = Robot("johh","Red", 40)
r2 = Robot("murry","Blue", 45)

r1.self_introduce()
r2.self_introduce()
```